# How do I print both Strings and Ints from a single text file?

Tags: java, file, io, parseint

I have a file pretty much as follows, but for a couple more names (each word and number is on a separate line) :
James
123
343
355
Kyle
136
689
680

I’ve been trying to read all these in as strings, and use parseInt to convert them to ints, as I need to find the avgs of the numbers following the names. It hasn’t worked though, and I’m curious as to how to print this file inside of Java. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is this you are looking for?

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class Main
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            //System.in is a standard input stream
            Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);    
            String name=sc.next();
            int a= sc.nextInt();
            int b= sc.nextInt();
            int c= sc.nextInt();
            int d=(a+b+c)/3;
            System.out.println("Average= " +d);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume for a second that under each name they can be a variable number of numerical values.  What we want to do is, while each line is number, keep adding them together and keep track of the number of lines we've read and when the line becomes a `String` probably print it out and setup for the next sequence.

I honestly think that people think that `Scanner` is only useful for reading user input or a file and forget that they can use multiple `Scanner`s to parse the same content (or help with it)

For example.  I set up `Scanner` to read each line of the file (as a `String`).  I then setup a second `Scanner` (for each line) and test to see if it's an `int` or not and take appropriate action, for example...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        // Just beware, I'm reading from an embedded resource here
        Scanner input = new Scanner(Test.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/Test.txt"));
        String name = null;
        int tally = 0;
        int count = 0;
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            Scanner parser = new Scanner(line);
            if (parser.hasNextInt()) {
                tally += parser.nextInt();
                count++;
            } else {
                if (name != null) {
                    System.out.println(name + "; tally = " + tally + "; average = " + (tally / (double) count));
                }

                name = parser.nextLine();
                tally = 0;
                count = 0;
            }
        }
        if (name != null) {
            System.out.println(name + "; tally = " + tally + "; average = " + (tally / (double) count));
        }
    }
}
```

which based on your example data, prints something like...

```
James; tally = 821; average = 273.6666666666667
Kyle; tally = 1505; average = 501.6666666666667
```